# VS2013: An error occurred while finding the resource dictionary / Type is not part of namespace

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml, visual-studio-2013

I'm working on a custom control, and here's what I have so far:

Themes/Generic.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Themes/ColorPicker.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Controls/ColorPicker.cs

```
namespace TrigDebugUtil.Controls
{
    public class ColorPicker : Control
    {
        #region Private Fields

        #endregion //Private Fields

        #region Properties
        public BitmapImage ColorWheelImage
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }
        #endregion //Properties

        static ColorPicker()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(ColorPicker), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(ColorPicker)));
        }

        public override void OnApplyTemplate()
        {
            base.OnApplyTemplate();
            WriteableBitmap ColorDrawboard;
        }
    }
}
```

Themes/ColorPicker.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TrigDebugUtil.Controls">


    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:ColorPicker}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:ColorPicker}">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                        <!-- <Image Source="{TemplateBinding ColorWheelImage}" /> -->
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

App.xaml

```
<Application x:Class="TrigDebugUtil.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:cont="clr-namespace:TrigDebugUtil.Controls"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">

    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Themes/Generic.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

            <Style TargetType="{x:Type cont:ColorPicker}" BasedOn="{StaticResource ColorPicker}" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

I now get a dozen of errors, all saying this:

Type or namespace "ColorPicker" does not exist in namespace "TrigDebugUtil.Controls"

An error occured while searching for resource dictionary "Themes/Generic.xaml"

if I replace the line in question with

`pack://application:,,,/Trig.DebugUtil;component/Themes/ColorPicker.xaml`

the error is replaced by a warning "Trig.DebugUtil" assembly not referenced by this project (free translation)

regardless of the error, the project seems to compile (no error messages in the console output, just in the error list)

Comment: Does `App.xaml` and `ColorPicker` control resides under same assembly or different assemblies?

Comment: both files are part of the same project, therefore it should be the same assembly. I should note however, that there are other projects in the solution (no reference to them however) and that I changed the assembly name in the properties of the project and in the Assembly.cs

Comment: Since you have declared template in separate xaml for ColorPicker `ColorPicker.xaml`, you need to merge that under your app resources. Try merging that OR either move the default template under `Generic.xaml`.

Comment: I actually moved the Template out of Generic.xaml into a separate file (pretty much the same issue before that). Isn't it enough to include the ColorPicker.xaml in the Generic.xaml and the generic.xaml in the app.xaml?

Comment: But for posted code for file `Generic.xaml`, I don't see ColorPicker file merge in it. You merged Generic.xaml within itself - `<ResourceDictionary Source="Themes/Generic.xaml" />`.

Comment: Sorry about that Typo, I edited that line when creating the post. Corrected now

Comment: Are you able to compile and run successfully OR it's just designer error you are seeing?

Comment: try `BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type cont:ColorPicker}}"` and see does it solve your issue.

Comment: @RohitVats, it compiles but crashes on startup with an xaml exception on the "BasedOn Line".

Comment: @pushpraj that resolves the crash but I don't know if its actually a solution. I never did it that way in my other projects (or in other projects i have seen) and I also wonder if that still does what it should do or won't have any other sideeffects later.

Comment: Alright, I don't know what exactly happend now but I commented out the img tag in the control template (that was causing an error as well) and now all other errors are gone as well and don't reappear when i remove the comment again. Still crashes without @pushpraj s fix though and in the mainwindow.xaml (where i use the control) it still says in the designer ColorPicker not in namespace Controls

Comment: You should use `BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type cont:ColorPicker}}"` for sure. The syntax you used only works for default controls provided by WPF but for custom controls you have to provide the exact type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type cont:ColorPicker}}"` for sure. The syntax you used only works for default controls provided by WPF but for custom controls you have to provide the exact type.

Also for TemplateBinding, property should be dependency property and not CLR property. ***ColorWheelImage you declared it as a normal CLR property but it should be declared as Dependency property***.

Syntax:

```
public BitmapImage ColorWheelImage
{
    get { return (BitmapImage)GetValue(ColorWheelImageProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ColorWheelImageProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty ColorWheelImageProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("ColorWheelImage", typeof(BitmapImage), 
                                 typeof(ColorPicker));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, although most of the errors just vanished, this one was the actual problem. I'm quite surprised about this actually as I did it in the "wrong" way in a different project and it works there without a problem, although on of those controls inherited from `ContentControl` rather than `Control`. Could you give some further explanation why it is necessary to give the full type?.

Comment: Also I was aware about the dependency properties, I was just stopped in the middle of the coding because of the other errors.

Comment: It is necessary to give the full type because by default WPF xaml parser will search for controls in `System.Windows.Controls` assembly, so you have to help XAML parser by telling it to search for it explicitly in your assembly and namespace. That's why in TargetType also you have to provide full type here `TargetType="{x:Type cont:ColorPicker}"`. Had it work than `TargetType=ColorPicker` would have work as well.

Comment: I do not question the correctness of your answer, but I'm confused. In another project, I have this custom control and it compiles and runs fine. http://pastebin.com/87YL4vzr

Comment: That was working fine because there you have set `x:Key` explicitly - `<Style x:Key="TimeSlider" TargetType="{x:Type Controls:TimeSlider}">`. So `BasedOn="{StaticResource TimeSlider}"` corresponds to that x:Key.

Comment: `BasedOn="{StaticResource ColorPicker}"` would work too in case `x:Key` is set on style defined in Generic.xaml `<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:ColorPicker}" x:Key="ColorPicker">`.

Comment: Thanks, that made it clear. Just one question to make sure I understand everything: THe whole "BasedOn"-Line is only necessary to set a default style / template?

Comment: `BasedOn` is needed in case you want to inherit one style from other. So BasedOn is analogous to inheritance in C#. When you want setters, triggers etc. from one style and don't want to repeat yourself, use `BasedOn` to inherit it from that style.

Comment: I didn't mean BasedOn in particular but rather the line its used in. if that line is removed, the control won't display because it wouldn't have a (default) control template set.

Comment: If you set `x:Key` then it's no more default style. If you omit setting x:Key for style defined in Generic.xaml, it will be treated as default style and will be applied to all ColorPicker in your app. So, with line `<Style TargetType="{x:Type cont:ColorPicker}" BasedOn="{StaticResource ColorPicker}" />` you are creating default style. This line can be omitted all together in case you have default style (without x:Key) declared under Generic.xaml.